# Webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText has provides not valid xml

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to use the Webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText to analyse a XML Code, but the compiler says it's not valid.

I saw, that the difference is that the Webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText provides the "-" Characters to fold-in and fold-out some regions as you know this from HTML.

Is there any way to get the clean Webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText?

Comment: You should be using an HTML library to parse XML.  It is acceptable to send XML in a body of an HTTP request.  The browser will not add dashes.  The dashes are being adding some place else.